Postgres geospatial query to return rows within some distance of longitude, latitude not working as expected
I am trying to load geospatial data into postgres and then use postgis to index the 2D point geography I make using the ST_MakePoint(float x, float y) function. Once the data is inserted and indexed I would like to query the data to get all rows within a specific distance of a provided longitude and latitude. My query looks like:
SELECT
    string_result
FROM public.geospatial_data
WHERE ST_DWithin(geo_point,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326),distance_in_meters);

My Question: When I query my database using the longitude, latitude order I get no results, but when I swap the order to latitude, longitude I get results. I don't understand why, or how to fix this so its consistently (longitude, latitude).
So my process of inserting the data into postgres is as follows:
-- Create an initial table to load data into postgres
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.geospatial_data_raw (
    longitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
    latitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
    string_result json
);

-- Copy data from aws s3 using the aws postgres extension aws_s3
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
    'geospatial_data_raw', '', '(format csv)',
    'aws_s3_bucket_name',
    'csv_file_name', 'aws_region'
);

-- Create table to store transformed data
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.geospatial_data (
    geo_point GEOGRAPHY(Point, 4326) NOT NULL,
    string_result json,
    updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT geospatial_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (geo_point)
);

-- Drop any indexes that exist on the table because this run occurs regularly
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS geospatial_data_idx;

-- Transform and upsert data from geospatial_data_raw table into geospatial_data table
INSERT INTO public.geospatial_data (geo_point, string_result, updated)
    SELECT
        ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude) as geo_point,
        string_result,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as updated
    FROM geospatial_data_raw
    ON CONFLICT (geo_point) DO UPDATE
    SET string_result = EXCLUDED.string_result, updated = EXCLUDED.updated;

-- Create index
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS geospatial_data_idx ON public.geospatial_data USING GIST (geo_point);

-- Delete any old rows
DELETE FROM public.geospatial_data
    WHERE updated < (
        SELECT MAX(updated) FROM public.geospatial_data
    );

-- Truncate the raw table for next load
TRUNCATE TABLE public.geospatial_data_raw;

I don't understand why my query that I use after loading does not work using the (longitude, latitude) order to make the 2D point to compare against other geography points in the geo_points column.
SELECT
    string_result
FROM public.geospatial_data 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(geo_point,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326),distance_in_meters);

But if i swap the order to (latitude, longitude) it works?
SELECT
    string_result
FROM public.geospatial_data 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(geo_point,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(latitude,longitude),4326),distance_in_meters);

Does anyone know why?

have yoz tried instaed of a point to use a , like  ST_Transform(geometry(
ST_Buffer(geography(
ST_Transform( point, 4326 )),
600000)),
900913) so that the point lng, lang is ion the circle

maybe the csv raw data has lat-long swapped?

@JGH I think this is it! I really thought the issue was in postgres but I checked the csv and saw that I'm loading the data into s3 as latitude, longitude, string_result, but then make the postgres table longitude, latitude, string_result. So the latitude got loaded into the postgres longitude column and vice versa. I'm running the process again now, but really think this is it. Thank you for the comment!
